# Ошибка выполнения при слиянии двух контейнеров в один алгоритмом stl merge

Tags: c++, stl

Вот собственно простенький пример кода, он собирается но при запуске выбрасывает исключение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    vector<int> va, vb, vc(6);

    va.push_back(10);
    va.push_back(100);
    va.push_back(2);

    vb.push_back(2);
    vb.push_back(50);
    vb.push_back(30);

    merge(va.begin(), va.end(), vb.begin(), vb.end(), vc.begin()); // здесь ошибка выполнения

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм `std::merge` требует, чтобы исходные диапазоны элементов были отсортированы. В результате выводится также отсортированная последовательность элементов.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<int> va, vb, vc(6);

    va.push_back(10);
    va.push_back(100);
    va.push_back(2);

    for ( int x : va ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    vb.push_back(2);
    vb.push_back(50);
    vb.push_back(30);

    for ( int x : vb ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( va.begin(), va.end() );
    std::sort( vb.begin(), vb.end() );
    merge(va.begin(), va.end(), vb.begin(), vb.end(), vc.begin()); // здесь ошибка выполнения

    for ( int x : vc ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
10 100 2 

2 50 30 

2 2 10 30 50 100
```

Согласно стандарту C++ (25.4 Sorting and related operations)

> 3 For all algorithms that take Compare, there is a version that **uses
>   operator<** instead. That is, comp(*i,*j) != false defaults to *i < *j
>   != false. For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work
>   correctly, comp has to induce **a strict weak ordering on the
>   values**.

Comment: спасибо @Vlad from Moscow вот бы никогда не подумал, что необходима сортировка

Comment: @perfect Смотрите также мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: понял, что все сравнивающие алгоритмы stl используют оператор сравнения (<) , а другие алгоритмы описанные стандарте 25.4.3 требуют отсортированного порядка. (английский недавно только осваивать начал, поэтому не судите строго за мой кривой английский язык)

Answer (score 3):

Функция std::merge требует чтобы входные массивы были отсортированы.